# Java 8 Convert a stream of set to Map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have written this lambda that is getting values from a map `<Code, Message>`contained inside an enum `MessageKeyRegistry` and creating adding to another map with Code as the key and the `MessageKeyRegistry` as the value.

```
Map<MessageKey, MessageKeyRegistry> keyMap = new HashMap<>();
    EnumSet.allOf(MessageKeyRegistry.class)
            .forEach(messageKeyRegistry -> messageKeyRegistry.getCodeToMessage().keySet()
                    .forEach(code -> keyMap.put(code, messageKeyRegistry)));
```

Now I want to satisfy the immutability concept of functional programming and write a lambda that returns an immutable map directly.

Comment: please show the `MessageKeyRegistry` structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have written this lambda that is..

You didn't write just a lambda, but a chain of methods *using* lambda expressions. one if them is `code -> keyMap.put(code, messageKeyRegistry)`.

Back to your question. You start with the iteration correctly (from the `EnumSet`), the next step is to realize what happens in the `forEach` methods.

- Extract codes from the set of keys using them as keys using `messageKeyRegistry`
- Using the extractor as a value `messageKeyRegistry`.

This is a job for `map`, however since the data structure is more complicated (collection in a collection), then `flatMap` would serve better. Finally, you'd result with something like:

```
Map<MessageKey, MessageKeyRegistry> keyMap = EnumSet.allOf(MessageKeyRegistry.class)
        .stream()
        .flatMap(messageKeyRegistry -> messageKeyRegistry.getCodeToMessage().keySet()
             .stream()
             .map(code -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(code, messageKeyRegistry)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

However, what you do has a drawback. I see the keys are overridden since there cannot be duplicates which is visible from the original solution, i.e. from this line that iterates at least once which implies the key may be overridden:

```
.forEach(code -> keyMap.put(code, messageKeyRegistry))
```

So what I suggest is rather group mapping using `Collectors.groupingBy` resulting in `Map<MessageKey, List<MessageKeyRegistry>>`:

```
Map<MessageKey, List<MessageKeyRegistry>> keyMap = EnumSet.allOf(MessageKeyRegistry.class)
        .stream()
        .flatMap(messageKeyRegistry -> messageKeyRegistry.getCodeToMessage().keySet()
            .stream()
            .map(code -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(code, messageKeyRegistry)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey));
```

For immutable map, if you mean a map that is read-only use the [`Collections.unmodifiableMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap-java.util.Map-) wrapper:

```
Map<MessageKey, List<MessageKeyRegistry>> unmodifiableKeyMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(keyMap);
```

Comment: The resulting `Map` should be immutable, per the OP.

Comment: To have an immutable map you should use `...Collectors.toUnmodifiableMap(...)`

Comment: @HadiJ, that method does not exist in Java 8 (which the OP has tagged).

Comment: I have forgotten to it while writing the answer. Wrapping into `Collections.unmodifiableMap` should help. I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the immutability concept of functional programming applying to java streams means immutable returning collections.
Let's consider more simple case

```java
final List<String> result = Stream.of("1", "2").collect(Collectors.toList());
result.add("3");
System.out.println(result);
System.out.println(result.getClass());
```

that outputs

```
[1, 2, 3]
class java.util.ArrayList
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the nicest but something like this should do:

```java
Map<MessageKey, MessageKeyRegistry> keyMap = EnumSet.allOf(MessageKeyRegistry.class)
       .stream()
       .flatMap(messageKeyRegistry -> messageKeyRegistry.getCodeToMessage().keySet().stream().map(code -> new Pair(code, messageKeyRegistry))
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getKey, Pair::getValue)));
```

Comment: Where does the `Pair` class come from?

Comment: `javafx` package, if you have one. Or you can use `Map.Entry` otherwise. (or create one yourself... it's just class to hold 2 values)